# Determine the probability for a pair (x, y) that:

Tags: actuarial-science

(a) y dies after the year of death of x

(b) y dies after x, assuming that times of death over the year of death are equally distributed.
Tabulate and compare the results obtained for a few concrete values.

I know how to calculate the probability that x will die in t years and that y will live t+1 years but how do I go further so that y dies after x without a concrete amount of years after x? I started with the probability that x dies in t years and y dies in t+1 years and got this: [image: this] Can I somehow use this to get to a) and b) of this exercise or am i going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Is the probability that y dies after x just $q_x$$_+$$_1$

Comment: or the product of all $q_k$ between x and y-1?

Comment: This is missing a lot of information. Please provide the entire question and all of its context